# Set Default Keyboard without having to long hold text input?

Tags: keyboard, command-line, default-applications

So I have successfully installed a new keyboard and enabled it in settings > keyboard and languages.    I have been able to set it to the default keyboard by doing a long press on an input field and selecting inputmethod... however I need to do this on several devices and its kind of lengthy ...

is there a way to set this with a shell command?

Comment: Question #2 is off-topic here.

Comment: is there a better place? I thought this was all things android including builds (we already compile the kernel with some custom modifications) I can remove 2. if you think I should. it would be nice to get a suggestion for an alternate place to ask (pretty sure its too specific for stackoverflow)

Comment: Please read our [help/on-topic]. This site is for user's of Android devices. If you're slinging code this isn't the right place for your question. This may be helpful: [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371)

Comment: since its mostly on topic can I leave question 2 and if someone happens to answer its cool? or will its presence result in this topics closure?

Comment: Apart from being off-topic, SE sites work best if questions are not combined. One question per post is the policy here. I'd recommend removing the second part, optionally asking it at [SO]. As for the first part: Are you asking for a one-time job, or are you looking for something to repeat more frequently? In the latter case, it might be possible using *Tasker*. But setting that up is not worth the time invested if you only need it once :)

Comment: As we "crossed" while saving our comments, you might have missed my edit: Are you asking for a one-time job, or are you looking for something to repeat more frequently? In the latter case, it might be possible using *Tasker.* But setting that up is not worth the time invested if you only need it once :)

Comment: its a one time job per device

Comment: thanks :) that answers my question(apparently I suck at search) ... I can delete this now? or should i leave it?

Comment: Leave it. We tend to keep duplicates as pointers for people with "limited search-Fu" :) No kidding. Search can be tricky even if you know the question exists, happens even to us "old hands" quite often, though we think ourselves having a quite cultivated "search-Fu"...

Comment: long press on an input field doesn't bring up anything to select the default keyboard for me..